# Regex to match software version

Tags: regex

When I query ssh.exe using the -V switch, I get back a string that looks something like this:

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.4
```

I need a regex filter that will only return "7.7". The problem is that I don't know what text will come before or after the version number so I'm trying to just return "a number, a dot, and a number" but I can't figure out how to isolate that first instance (7.7) and ignore the second one (2.4.6).

Aside from matching too many instances, this works:

```
\d\.\d
```

So, how would I modify this to ignore the extra text?

Thanks.

Comment: Try it like this [`^[a-zA-Z_]+(\d+\.\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/vm8dzA/1). That way you use an anchor `^` to assert the start of the line and a character class in which you specify which characters to match. Your value is in the first capturing group.

Comment: This might get you started: [**`^\D+(\d+\.\d+)`**](https://regex101.com/r/fKN4p7/1/)

Comment: Where are you using the regex? Please show your code.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the global attribute in your regular expression. Like this:

```
/\d\.\d/
```

Not like this:

```
/\d\.\d/g
```

Comment: Not all regex flavors use a `/g` flag/notation. This might work or not depending on how OP uses the regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookahead to check if there is a dot after the second digit

```
^(\w+)(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2})(?!\.)
```

In my case, i'm using the start string character `^` followed by any words multiple time (`(\w+)`). Then i'm using the next part of the regex to make sure there is only one or two digit seperated by a dot. (`(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2})`) and then we check if there is no dot after that (`(?!\.)`).
The full match of the regex will returns the string from the beginning to the version, but you can use capture group to isolate the version. 
I've created a [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/lBebP4/1) if you wish to test more cases.

Comment: [dimitryro answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51105214/5784924) works great for your case, but will not work for a case that does not contains an underscore before the version. But if you are sure there is always an underscore before the version, use their answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookbehind to consider only one with `_` in the beginning:

```
(?<=_)\d\.\d
```

Answer (score 0):

You could match from the start of the string `^` an uppercase, lowercase or an underscore `[a-zA-Z_]+` followed by capturing the pattern for the digits `(\d+\.\d+)` in a capturing group.

[`^[a-zA-Z_]+(\d+\.\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/vm8dzA/1)